# A word for non-physical forces that affect the physical world

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that can be used to classify all forces that are attached to some sort of physical entity and affect the world around them. Forces in this sense is like Gravity, like it is intrinsic to an object and can impart some sort of change on it's surroundings. Examples of these forces would be Gravity, Heat, Light, basically anything with a physical source. Including things like Forces that affect objects because they exist like time (or like the ability to decay) Really just a synonym of force that is specifically non-physical the rest is just in case there is some word in physics for these things.

Comment: I don't get it.  Gravity, light, heat are all physical things.

Comment: I'm was thinking like intangible or without shape (as far as we know) sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A force that is not of the physical realm but which influences the physical realm would be a metaphysical force.

> Metaphysical : II. Other senses relating more generally to things which are immaterial, imaginary, preternatural, or supernatural.
> 4.
> Thesaurus »

**a. Designating that which is immaterial, incorporeal, or supersensible (esp. in explicit contrast to physical).**

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/117349?redirectedFrom=metaphysical#eid)

Comment: Gravity isn't a metaphysical concept.

Comment: @HotLicks The question _heading_ asks for non-physical force that affects the physical world. And nobody, yet, has understood what gravity is - Einstein only tells us that it is a warping of space. He does not say _how_ it is warped.

Comment: I don't get it. Gravity, light, heat are all physical things. – Hot Licks Nov 28 at 2:28
    // ... //   I'm was thinking like intangible or without shape (as far as we know) sorry for the confusion – 9unk  Nov 28 at 2:29. 'Metaphysical' is incorrect here.

Comment: @NigelJ Not expressing "how" doesn't imply "non-physical". The fine makers of Coke-a-cola wisely refuse to tell most of us how they brew their beverage, but they most certainly use physical means.

Comment: @jimm101 I understand it to be self evident that physical forces and matter _must_ be the result of that which is non-physical.

Comment: @NigelJ You'll find that not many scientists or philosophers use the "self-evident" argument, and for good reason. This is quickly becoming word salad.